# Extension points for converting projects?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-pde

I am looking for a way to hook into the import process of a project and execute my custom code in order to upgrade the `.cproject` file of the corresponding project.

I found the following two extension points:

1. `org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.projectConverter`
2. `org.eclipse.cdt.core.projectConverter`

By adding extension point 1, I noticed that there's the new option 'Convert To...' in the project's context menu. This works great, but I want to start the conversion process automatically. How can I do this?

By adding extension point 2, nothing happened. Unfortunately, I did not find any useful information for which purpose they can be used.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it on import? What if a user uses a workspace with the project in it already. Or checks out a older version of the project from source control after already having imported it? If you do want to do it on import, write your own import wizard and teach your users to use it or add a resource changed listener. But IMHO it may be better to do the upgrade on access. When your custom code needs something from the project setting, check to see if the version is up to date, and if not upgrade it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That sounds reasonable. Do you know how I can upgrade projects on access? Is there an extension point for it?

Comment: By access I mean when "you" (your code) accesses, no extension point. If you are trying to upgrade a project before CDT accesses contents, then you are in a bit more trouble because AFAIK there are no hooks to do that. In that case you have to ask your user to import/convert the project manually (or detect the issue with resource change listener and then ask the user to do it). Be careful if you try to change CDT's datastructures in unexpected ways as that can easily open up a race condition. Can you expand on what you are trying to upgrade?

Comment: @JonahGraham I just want to update element IDs of the `.cproject` XML file.

Comment: @JonahGraham Also, it is documented that the`toId` and `fromId` attributes of `org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.projectConverter` should accept regular expressions, but I can't get it to work with regular expressions, only if they match exactly the ID. Is this a known limitation?